# remove <p> tags arround images

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I have a string:

```
$str = '<p>line</p>
        <p><img src="images/01.jpg">line with image</p>
        <p><img src="images/02.jpg">line with image</p>';
```

and want to turn it into:

```
$str = '<p>line</p>
        <img src="images/01.jpg"><p>line with image</p>
        <img src="images/02.jpg"><p>line with image</p>';
```

I tried

```
$result = preg_replace('%(.*?)<p>\s*(<img[^<]+?)\s*</p>(.*)%is', '$1$2$3', $str);
```

but it's only removing one image not the second one. Please suggest a regex.

Comment: We will suggest after you show something you've tried already.

Comment: $result = preg_replace('%(.*?)<p>\s*(<img[^<]+?)\s*</p>(.*)%is', '$1$2$3', $str)
 but it only removing one image not the second one

Comment: Use a parser, regex and HTML are not good friends.

Comment: how to do that?

Comment: For example: http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/ or http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php

Comment: can you share dom code to solve this?

Comment: how about [`$str = preg_replace('/<p>(<img[^>]*>)/', '$1<p>', $str);`](https://eval.in/735111) (depending on your input it's not recommended parsing html with regex as mentioned already).

Comment: Because people keep suggesting regex: This http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Comment: @bobblebubble if I use this [link](https://eval.in/735333) then its not gonna work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found the solution I guess. these two regex together solves my problem:

```
$str = '<p>line</p>
        <p><img src="images/01.jpg">line with image</p>
        <p>line with image<img src="images/02.jpg"></p>';
$str = preg_replace('/<p>(<img[^>]*>)/', '$1<p>', $str);
$str = preg_replace('/(<img[^>]*>)<\/p>/', '</p>$1', $str);
echo $str;
```

o/p:

```
<p>line</p>          
<img src="images/01.jpg"><p>line with image</p>          
<p>line with image</p><img src="images/02.jpg">
```

here is the working [link](https://eval.in/735339) and
thanks a lot every body and specially @bobblebobble

Answer (score 1):

This will remove `<p>` tag from around img (using DOM parser)

```
    $html = str_get_html('<p>line</p>
            <p><img src="images/01.jpg">line with image</p>
            <p><img src="images/02.jpg">line with image</p>');


    foreach($html->find('img') as $img) {    
  $str ="<p>".$img->parent()->plaintext."</p>";
  $img->parent()->outertext=$img;
  $img->parent()->outertext .=$str;

}
echo $html;
```

o/p:

```
<p>line</p>          
<img src="images/01.jpg">
  line with image          
<img src="images/02.jpg">
  line with image
```

Comment: but i want to wrap the text with p tag like <p>line with image</p> please help